# What does “Case sensitivity is a function of the Linux filesystem not the Linux operating system” mean?

Tags: bash, filesystems, zsh, case-sensitivity

I just read the following sentence:

> Case Sensitivity is a function of the Linux filesystem NOT the Linux operating system.

What I deduced from this sentence is if I'm on a Linux machine but I am working with a device formatted using the Windows File System, then case sensitivity will NOT be a thing.

I tried the following to verify this:

```
$ ~/Documents: mkdir Test temp

$ ~/Documents: touch Test/a.txt temp/b.txt

$ ~/Documents: ls te*
b.txt
```

And it listed only the files within the `temp` directory, which was expected because I am inside a Linux Filesystem.

When I navigated to a Windows File System (NOTE: I am using WSL2), I still get the same results, but I was expecting it to list files inside both directories ignoring case sensitivity.

```
$ /mnt/d: mkdir Test temp

$ /mnt/d: touch Test/a.txt temp/b.txt

$ /mnt/d: ls te*
b.txt
```

I tried it with both bash and zsh.

I feel that it's somehow related to bash (or zsh), because I also read that bash enforces case sensitivity even when working with case insensitive filesystems.

This test works on Powershell, so it means that the filesystem is indeed case insensitive.

Comment: What does "case-sensitive" mean in many non-latin languages?

Comment: Where did you read the sentence? It does not sound like something that is true in all contexts, since many parts of the Linux kernel and of Linux-based operating systems that deal with files are indeed case sensitive.

Comment: @JeremyBoden That's a good, but separate, question. See https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr21/tr21-5.html for some discussion of caseless matching across various languages. ("Case sensitive" is pretty straightforward; "case insensitive" is the complicated one.)

Comment: Keep in mind that NTFS is [actually case-sensitive](https://superuser.com/questions/364057/why-is-ntfs-case-sensitive), and it's just a *Windows* compatibility layer that makes it not so. If your Windows file system is using NTFS, odds are it's actually case sensitive as well

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here, you're running:

```
ls te*
```

Using a feature of your *shell* called *globbing* or *filename generation* (pathname expansion in POSIX), not of the Linux system nor of any filesystem used on Linux.

`te*` is expanded *by the shell* to the list of files that match that pattern.

To do that, the shell requests the list of entries in the current directory from the system (typically using the `readdir()` function of the C library, which underneath will use a system-specific system call (`getdents()` on Linux)), and then match each name against the pattern.

And unless you've configured your shell to do that matching case insensitively (see `nocaseglob` options in zsh or bash) or use glob operators to toggle case insensitivity (like the `(#i)` extended glob operator in `zsh`), `te*` will only expand to the list of files  whose name as reported by `readdir()` starts with `te`, even if pathname resolution on the system or file system underneath is case insensitive or can be made to be like NTFS.

Comment: So, basically you mean to say that I am not testing the statement correctly, could you please tell how can I validate the authenticity of that statement?

Comment: Create a file called "TEST". Then try to create one called "test". You can do this on native linux filesystems, have two files with different case only. But not on Windows filesystem. Similarly, create "TEST" and then do "cat test" to see the contents - works on Windows,

Comment: @pjc50 this is unambigously correct for VFAT, but not for NTFS, where at least `ntfs-3g` uses POSIX namespace by default, thus allowing filenames in a single directory to differ only by case.

Comment: @pjc50 On FAT, the name with a dot still refers to the same file.  For example `TEST.`.

Comment: @Ruslan Not just `ntfs-3g` - the Windows implementation allows for the same feature, although it's probably not a good idea to enable it on Windows globally (although personally I never had an interest in case-sensitivity in file systems so I never tried). You can also enable it on a per-folder basis which can be useful when working with git repositories where there might be files that only differ by case.

Comment: @Ruslan I think you're saying that not all Windows filesystems are case-insensitive: for example NTFS (3g at least) is case-sensitive. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @LarsH basically, yes. But note that NTFS is not intrinsically case sensitive: Windows namespace is case insensitive, and `ntfs-3g` can follow this with mount options like `ignore_case,windows_names`.

Answer (score 18):

As [Vojtech explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/656008/86440), NTFS is case sensitive. Trying it on a FAT file system will work, but only if you use a case-folding variant, *i.e.* `msdos` on Linux (I don’t know if there’s an equivalent on WSL). With this variant of FAT, file names are all lower-cased, so `Test` shows up as `test`.

There are a number of aspects to consider regarding case sensitivity in file systems:

- whether the file system itself stores case information;
- whether the expected use of the file system considers case;
- whether the file system driver or the operating system maps case, *i.e.* whether a file can be found ignoring case;
- *how* to map case.

Historical FAT, as implemented in the `msdos`, is somewhere in between the first two: technically, FAT can store case, but in practice it wasn’t used that way, and MS-DOS and its clones folded case (so `readme.txt` and `README.TXT` and `ReAdMe.TxT` are all valid ways to access `README.TXT`). Windows preserves this behaviour, even on case-preserving file systems (including VFAT and NTFS). The `msdos` file system driver handles this by mapping all file names to lowercase, which isn’t quite right but produces consistent results and avoids problems with Unix-style tools’ and users’ expectations. So on Linux, mounting a file system using the `msdos` driver means that `README.TXT` can only be accessed through `readme.txt`, not through any of the variants including those shown above.

Your quote stems from the fact that the Linux *kernel* itself doesn’t particularly care, at least on the surface: one could imagine a file system where `open("README.TXT")` and `open("ReAdMe.TxT")` would open the same file. Indeed XFS can be configured in this way, at least for ASCII file names (it is then case preserving, but provides case-insensitive lookups). However things quickly get more complicated for general-purpose scenarios, and there has been much discussion over the years; see for example [Filesystems and case insensitivity](https://lwn.net/Articles/772960/), [Case-insensitive filesystem lookups](https://lwn.net/Articles/754508/), and [Case-insensitive ext4](https://lwn.net/Articles/784041/) on LWN.

Comment: I am just a beginner in all this stuff so it will take some time to wrap my head around this. But meanwhile could you please tell that is it anyhow related to BASH? I've added few points in my question if you could check that.

Comment: See also the `lowntfs-3g` fuse driver to get a similar behaviour as that of that `msdos` driver you're mentioning.

Comment: It is not related to the shell you are using.  NTFS is case-sensitive, the normal WIn32 API's are not.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee a typical Linux-based operating system is not a monolith, but composed of a number of components created by a number of unrelated projects. Most Linux file systems are case sensitive, so many projects assume file names are case sensitive, and may behave surprisingly if the underlying file system is case insensitive. BASH is at least somewhat aware of this, and has options to help with this, but its defaults are still to assume case sensitivity, like most Linux applications would.

Answer (score 10):

That's because [NTFS is also case sensitive](https://superuser.com/questions/364057/why-is-ntfs-case-sensitive), but Windows hides it from users. FAT is case insensitive, you can check by trying to create `test` and `Test` directories in the same directory:

```
$ ls
test
$ mkdir Test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Test’: File exists
$ mkdir TEST
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘TEST’: File exists
```

It's actually more a little bit more complicated than this and your `ls` test won't work even with FAT because it actually is [case preserving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_preservation) -- it won't allow you to create `Test` and `test` directories but it still makes difference between those two cases (and between `T*` and `t*`) so `ls t*` for `test` and `Temp` won't list content of both.

Comment: That's really confusing for me, so does the statement actually mean anything and is there a way to test it?

Comment: I feel that it's somewhere related to Bash (or ZSH), because I also read that Bash enforces case sensitivity even when working with case insensitive file systems. And this test works on Powershell so it means that the file system is indeed case insensitive.

Comment: I think the `mkdir` I showed tests the statement: you can't create `Test` and `test` in same directory on (V)FAT filesystem, but you can do it on NTFS or Ext4 and XFS and other linux native filesystems. That should be enough to show that case sensitivity is based on filesystem and not operating system. The case preservation makes it a little bit confusing and I didn't realize this when answering initially but I think Stephen's answer made this clearer.

Comment: So you mean it doesn't matter what shell I am using I will always get the same results in this case? In short shell doesn't play any role here, right?

Comment: In theory the shell could "play a role" in this if it was programmed to do that, but that's not the case with "normal" linux shells.

Answer (score 2):

I question the quote text; An operating system is case-agnostic--it is not usually case sensitive or insensitive. Instead, the command line shells and/or file system drivers are what make case matter or not.

And even then is is not that simple: Computers are numerical machines, not textual. The signals and data all have numerical values associated. Text usually uses the 7-bit ASCII code (in 8-bit groups, so the 8th bit is always 0 in ASCII. Unicode, ANSI, etc, complicate this even more.), where upper and lower case codes are different. Here are the codes for 'A' and 'a' (in binary):

```
A  01000001
a  01100001
```

At various levels (kernel, shell, files system driver, CPU, and others), the numerical values are case agnostic since there is no such thing as an upper-/lower-case 1 and 0.

Also be aware of the concept of "globbing". Globbing is the idea of using '*' or '?' to "match" anything--even nothing--in different scenarios and rules, depending one which glob character was used.

In a typical Unix-like shell, such as Bash, the shell will do the globbing: in `ls *`, the shell will expand the '*' with a list of matched filenames, ***before*** starting the `ls` command and pass it the list of matched names, not the '*'.

A typical "msdos" style shell will not do this. In this situation, the `cmd.exe` shell would start the `ls.exe` command (*assuming it exists!*) and pass it a single '*'. It is then up to the `ls.exe` command to handle the expansion of '*' according to it's own rules.

Add in the file systems... EXT (Unix) file systems are case sensitive. FAT file systems are case insensitive (look at an old FAT floppy image--the filenames are stored using UPPERCASE ASCII), which is complicated more with FAT32 and LFN (long file name support). And NTFS, which tries to bridge the gap by being both--NTFS is generally  case-preserving while ignoring case when it tries to match a filename (remember as well, the filename is stored as a sequence of numerical data).

In the example given, `ls te*`, the bash shell gives you additional options. For example, try `ls [Tt]e*`, and it will match both 'Test' and 'temp', but not 'TECH'.

As you can see, the situation is very complex. And the exact question asked about the statement given is also a complex situation, further complicated because the statement is questionable without additional qualifications and context.

Comment: NTFS is really funny with cases - it stores the rules on the disk itself! It's modern enough that Microsoft was aware of the fact that there's no single global rule how case sensitivity works, but you need _a_ rule in order to exchange disks between systems.

Answer (score 1):

There is a point that is worth calling out specifically, that potentially puts some of these answers into context.

On Linux, all system calls that deal with filenames deal with strings of bytes. That is to say, that whenever a program asks to do something with the file system, it will specify any filenames it is working with as a string of bytes, and any filenames that are returned to it will be strings of bytes. Often (although this is not enforced), these strings will contain ASCII or UTF-8 encoded text, and the binary representations of upper and lower case letters in these encodings are different. So anything that treats filenames as "just binary data" is case sensitive.

Once these requests get to the filesystem driver, some filesystems will interpret file names case sensitively (typically ones created for Linux or other Unix operating systems) and some will interpret file names case insensitively (typically ones created for other operating systems, such as Windows). But these are internal implementation details that programs cannot see - all they see are strings of bytes.

Typically, programs will not attempt to determine whether the filesystem they are running on is case sensitive or not, and many programs will implicitly assume that filesystems are case sensitive (since this is the simplest to implement). Some may have configuration options to allow them to work with case, but remember that all the filesystem will ever talk to them about is strings of bytes, so this isn't something that programs can work out from the filenames they see.

Answer (score 0):

I think the quote is not only, as [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/656025/479642) correctly points out, ambiguous and context-dependent, but altogether misleading, because of the use of "sensitive" and "function". Actually, both the Linux kernel and Linux or GNU/Linux or Unixoid operating systems, as well as native Linux file systems, are "case-sensitive" exactly *because* they have absolutely *no concept of "case"*. For Linux, the difference between `a` and `A` is just the same as that between `a` and `b`: two different code points, one (or more) bits switched (and neither below decimal 32 nor above decimal 127, to leave special cases aside). Any idea of a somewhat particular relation between lower- and uppercase "A" that is something else than that between two code points is either imposed by other contexts (like C code) or pure convention (adherence to which may still be expected by tools, though!).

The confusion is unavoidable because not having a concept of something completely contradicts our notion of being sensitive about the same thing. If a spell checker claims to be grammar-sensitive, we expect it to recognize rules beyond pure spelling, or, in order to be less metaphorical, its programmers to have implemented functions that in some way or other deal with the concept of grammar. And while the Linux programmers (in any of the meanings mentioned above) certainly all have a concept of character case, they just did not implement any of that in the system.

Also, *not* having a concept about something is usually not regarded a function. However, mapping `a` to `A`, thereby either not allowing `test.txt` besides `TEST.TXT` or, worse, making the two indiscernable, *is* a function that has to be explicitly implemented in the OS or the file system or whatever layer we're talking about in a specific context. And this function disguises as the absence of a function by calling it "case-*in*sensitivity". What it provides is an interface that allows for the user being insensitive about holding or not holding the shift key when typing a filename. (And the only possible explanation of why someone once thought this to be advantageous is the common misconception that less expressive user interfaces are easier to understand - but that is beyond the scope of the question.)